# RxJava runs on same blocking UI Thread and doesn't show AlertDialog

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I'm trying to use RxJava to show a AlertDialog during loading of some method. It doesn't work, UI is blocked for 2 seconds and when stepping through it with Debugger, the debugger shows that it is run on the UI thread. I've added the Schedulers.IO, so what am I doing wrong?

```
boolean initialize() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return true;
}

public AlertDialog showSomePopup(Context context, String msg) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Loading...")
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final AlertDialog dialog = showSomePopup(this, "Waiting ..");

    Single.just(initialize())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use Observable.interval(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS) instead of Single.just

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `.subscribe()` is not being called until the `initialize()` method doesn't emit (i.e. as you're using `.just()`, until `initialize()` doesn't return.

Comment: So how should I rewrite it?

Comment: As @Hans Wurst suggests.

Comment: Just to clarify, even if what my answer describes is true, this was not the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your initialize function should return an `Observable` that the caller can subscribe to. In your case, you start the sequence by calling `initialize()` and then waiting for the result to return. What you should do:

```
Single<Boolean> initialize() {
    return Single.fromCallable(new Callable<Boolean>() {
       @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now you can just put in the code that you had like this:

```
initialize()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
            if(aBoolean == true) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

and it will work as you wanted it to.

Comment: It is a overkill to use create from observable. Observable does provided other factory methods for this kind, such as "defer" or "fromCallable". Furthermore Completeable is more suiting for this use-case.

Comment: Changed it to Completeable. Although the author mentioned he wanted to have data being fetched from the background, so Observable might be suited for his case. But you are right :)

Comment: Did not read something about fetching data. Just invoking a method that returns true/ false. If data should be fetch it is recommanded to use a Single for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: thanks guys. But the initialize method does return a boolean. So I should change it to new Consumer<Boolean>() I think?

Comment: If you have the case that true/false are important for your return value, yes. Then use a Single in `initialize` instead and subscribe with a `Consumer<Boolean>`

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up answer to @Xavier Rubio Jansana right answer.
Use **Completeable** for methods which do finish or fail.

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        init();
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            //.observeOn() AndroidScheduler
            .subscribe(() -> {
               // dismiss action
});

private void init() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer:

```
Single<Boolean> initialize() {
    return Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(@NonNull SingleEmitter<Boolean> e) throws Exception {
            e.onSuccess(true);
        }
    });
}

public AlertDialog showSomePopup(Context context, String msg) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Loading...")
            .setMessage(msg)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null).create();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final AlertDialog dialog = showSomePopup(this, "lol");
    dialog.show();

    initialize().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSuccess(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Boolean aBoolean) throws Exception {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog create() is missing in the creation of AlertDialog().Add this before showing.

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Loading...")
        .setMessage(msg)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
        .create()
        .show();
```